# Using a sum of values as a condition (SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks roughly like this

```
Year    Species   Count
1979    A         0
1980    A         10
1981    A         4
1982    A         3
1979    B         0
1980    B         1
1981    B         2
1982    B         3
1979    C         9
1980    C         14
1981    C         2
1982    C         1
```

What i want is to return all Year, Species, Count for those species that have a total count (as in summed over all years) of 10 or more. so for a total count of 20 i would want it to just return

```
1979    C         9
1980    C         14
1981    C         2
1982    C         1
```

i played around with having but havent really gotten anything useful (total SQL beginner)

Comment: you'd need to put in a running total derived column, and a having clause to limit the results to whatever rows where the running total <=20.

Comment: Why wouldn't A be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiesy.  You already have the counts.  Group on species and filter table on the results of the subquesy.  You can get the same functionality with an exists or a join also.

```
SELECT
    [YEAR]
    ,SPECIES
    ,[COUNT]
FROM TABLE
WHERE SPECIES IN (
    SELECT SPECIES
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY SPECIES
    HAVING SUM([COUNT]) > 20)
)
```

Adding some addtional explanation for BootstrapBill

Group by "makes multiple sets" for each unique value of the GROUP BY column.  That allows the aggregate function SUM() act on only one set of the GROUP BY values at a time.  HAVING is sort of like a WHERE clause for the GROUP BY statement that allows you to apply a predicate.  The only fields allowed to be returned by a GROUP BY are the grouped column itself and the results of any aggregate function(s), you need to join back to or filter the original set to get the other columns your are targeting in the query.

And I apoligze, I did not see where the OP stated this was for MySql.  The core concept is the same so I am leaving the answer.  [] are MS SQL syntax for escaping the keywords COUNT and YEAR.

Comment: That solution will work but MySQl doesn't, to the best of my knowledge, use square brackets for columns that might be reserved words. Use backticks instead.

Comment: The square brackets are T-SQL syntax.

Comment: OP asked for MySQL solution, not SQL Server/Transact-SQL

Comment: that does it, although i am still trying to figure out what it does exactly...

i dont use the [], but anyway....


i still dont get what exactly the group by and having does. thats what i tried to get to work before i posted, but it remains a bit of a mystery.

how does it know to only sum the counts within one species?

Comment: I added additional explanation.  David Faber's comment will give you the answer about the square braces.  That was my mistake as I did not see the question was inteaded for MySql.

Comment: thank you for your answer and elaboration. i even managed to go slightly beyond what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can do this using aggregation and a `join`:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select species, count(*) as cnt
      from table
      group by species
     ) s
     on t.species = s.species
where s.cnt >= 10;
```

Comment: why a join for only 1 table?

Comment: This kind of query requires a self-join.

Comment: Alternately one might use the `HAVING` clause in the subquery and avoid the `WHERE` in the outer query.

Comment: @tung . . . Because you need to calculate the total count.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `GROUP BY` with the `SUM()` aggregate function and `HAVING` clause (similar to `WHERE`, but for groups instead of rows), combined with a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.`Year`, t1.`Species`, t1.`Count`
  FROM mytable t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `Species`, SUM(`Count`)
      FROM mytable
     GROUP BY `Species`
    HAVING SUM(`Count`) >= 20
) t2
    ON t1.`Species` = t2.`Species`
```